# Bevel Modifier is Not Showing in Object Mode

Tags: modifiers, edges, topology, bevel, object-mode

I've applied a bevel modifier, and set the edge data to "weight". As you can see in the upcoming image, the modifier is working; but only in edit mode:

[image]

When I go back into edit mode, it looks like this:

[image]

Does anyone know why this might be happening? I've made sure all of my faces were quads, and I also made sure I didn't have any double vertices.Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The reason this was not working was because my boolean was above the bevel in my modifier stack. As soon as I moved it down, it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the info. My bevel modifier isn't showing at all. It works if I make a new object but not on the one I am working on for some reason.